# Passing custom TemplateRef to NgxDatatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

The tables on the project I'm working on have a certain wrapper around them, so in order to avoid code duplication I'm looking for a way to create a template where each component passes an ng-template, and it gets rendered inside the custom table template.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233192/how-to-pass-an-ngx-datatable-column-inside-a-wrapped-by-another-component-n) approach, however when trying to reproduce it on a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tw9bq), I can't seem to get it working.

I'm trying to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813526/common-wrapper-component-for-ngx-datatable) approach, where columns are defined on the component code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1299), this is not possible.

From reading the comment, this is apparently due to [angular itself](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563), which does not support content projection in more than 2 levels. So I guess for know you are stuck with defining columns in code.

That's probably why the SO solution you found was never accepted